# What are tunnels? Why have these on my vps?

Tags: linux, networking

I have a big big big amount of networks interfaces and some tunnels.

I have no idea of who and why created these.

Is there a way to disable a network interface and/or a tunnel and/or discover it source ?

```
# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 
4: teql0: <NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 100
    link/void
5: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
7: gretap0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: erspan0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1464 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: ip_vti0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
10: ip6_vti0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1364 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/tunnel6 :: brd :: permaddr 
11: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
12: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/tunnel6 :: brd :: permaddr 
13: ip6gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1448 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/gre6 :: brd :: permaddr 

# ip tunnel show
tunl0: any/ip remote any local any ttl inherit nopmtudisc
gre0: gre/ip remote any local any ttl inherit nopmtudisc
ip_vti0: ip/ip remote any local any ttl inherit nopmtudisc key 0
sit0: ipv6/ip remote any local any ttl 64 nopmtudisc 6rd-prefix 2002::/16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the interfaces you're seeing are a leftover from old Linux (possibly kernel 2.2 or 2.4 era). Back then `ip tunnel add` wasn't a thing yet, instead you would *always* have a "gre0" interface available – if you wanted to actually set up a GRE tunnel, you would just `ifconfig gre0 up`. (After doing this, gre1 would become available.)

In recent Linux versions, these can be disabled using `fb_tunnels=none` as a kernel command-line option.

Comment: could you help me to use this 'command-line option' in a running server?